# Why is my password reset link logic showing undefined in my Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to create a route that sends someone a JWT token reset link. The Route that I am having issues with is as follows:

```
// REQUIREMENTS
require("dotenv").config();
const express       =   require("express"),
    expressSanitizer=   require("express-sanitizer"),
    router          =   express.Router(),
    passport        =   require("passport"),
    User            =   require("../models/user"),
    middleware      =   require("../middleware"),
    mailchimp       = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing'),
    request         = require('request'),
    https           = require('https'),
    nodemailer      =   require("nodemailer"),
    jwt             = require('jsonwebtoken');
    
const JWT_SECRET = "jwt_secret";

router.post('/forgot-password', (req, res, next) =>{
    let userEmail       = req.body.email;
    let link;
    User.findOne({'email': req.query.email}, function(err, username){
        let userEmail = req.body.email;
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        var message;
        if(username) {
            console.log(username);
            message = "email exists";
            console.log(message);
            // SEND TOKEN HERE
            const secret = JWT_SECRET + username.password;
            const payload = {
                id: username.id,
                email: userEmail
            };
            let token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, {expiresIn: '15m'});
            // CHECK URL PARAMS
            let link = process.env.URL`/${username.id}/${token}`;
            console.log(link);
            console.log(payload);
            return link, payload;
        }
    });
    
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            clientId: authClient,
            clientSecret: authCSecret
        }
    });
    
    // Email Data
    let mailOptions = {
        from: *****, // sender address
        to: userEmail, // list of receivers
        replyTo: *****,
        subject: 'Reset Your Password', // Subject line
        html: '<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"rel="stylesheet"/><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.0.1/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><p class="lead">Hey, it looks like you forgot your password.</p><p class="card-text">Follow the link below to reset your password.<div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary my-3" href="'+link+'" target="_blank">click here</a></div></p><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.0.1/mdb.min.js"></script>', // html body
        auth: {
            user: authUser,
            refreshToken: authRefreshToken,
            accessToken: authAccessToken,
            expires: 3599
        }
    };
    
    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        res.send("A link has been sent to your email.");
    });

});
```

I have confirmed the Nodemailer part works. I am just at a loss why the link is always showing as undefined when in my console it prints out a valid link to follow. All help would be appreciated!